# Hideous blow (Warlock) with monk

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, warlock

Can hideous blow be used with fury of blows (or other monk special attacks) if one is multi-classing a monk and warlock in 5th edition?

Comment: Where are you finding "Hideous Blow"?

Answer (score 5):

### No.

To my knowledge, Hideous Blow was an invocation for the Warlock in D&D 3.5, but has not been included in subsequent editions.  Material from different editions is not compatible by default, but you may be able to work with your GM to create a custom invocation if you wish.

Flurry of Blows states that "immediately after you take the Attack action on your turn, you can spend 1 ki point to make two unarmed strikes as a bonus action." (SRD, p. 27)

Hideous Blow allowed a Warlock to take a standard action (Action, in 5e parlance) to make a melee attack.  If successful, the target was also effected by the Eldritch Blast of the Warlock.  A potential homebrew solution would be for the Warlock to take the custom "Hideous Blow" invocation, which would allow the Warlock to add his Eldritch Blast damage to a melee attack.  I don't know that it would be particularly well-balanced in this form, as it might eclipse the functionality of the Thirsting Blade invocation, which allows Blade Pact Warlocks to attack twice when taking an attack action.  The balance of a new Warlock invocation could make for another potential question - good luck!